# How to use the GCC attribute 'format'?

Tags: gcc, attributes, format, warnings, printf

Here is a piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void MyPrintf(char const* format, va_list args);
void MyVariadicPrintf(char const* format, ...);

void MyPrintf(char const* format, va_list args)
{
    vprintf(format, args);
}

void MyVariadicPrintf(char const* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    MyPrintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int, char*)
{
    MyVariadicPrintf("%s" /* missing 2nd argument */);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with GCC 4.0, running Xcode on Mac OS X Leopard.
`-Wformat` and `-Wmissing-format-attribute` are enabled.
This code gives a warning on line 9 (call to `vprintf`), suggesting that `MyPrintf` could use the 'format' attribute:

> function might be possible candidate for 'printf' format attribute

So I add the attribute this way (not sure if this is right):

```
void MyPrintf(char const* format, va_list args) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 0)));
```

The previous warning disappears and the same warning now appears on line 16 (call to `MyPrintf`), suggesting that `MyVariadicPrintf` could use the 'format' attribute.
So I add the attribute this way (pretty sure this is right this time):

```
void MyVariadicPrintf(char const* format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
```

And now I get the expected warning on line 22 (call to `MyVariadicPrintf`):

> too few arguments for format

1. Did I do this right?
2. I noticed that on `MyPrintf` declaration, if I delete the attribute part, I'll still get the wanted warning on line 22. I also noticed that in this attribute part, changing the index from 1 to 2 won't give any warning or error. Which one is right and what is the goal of the attribute on this function?
3. If I add the following function `MyVariadicPrintfT` and call it (specialized with `char`), I'll get the warning suggesting to use the 'format' attribute on this function. I think it's impossible because the `format` argument is dependent on the templated type. Am I right?

   ```
    template<typename Type>
    void MyVariadicPrintfT(Type const* format, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        MyPrintf(format, args);
        va_end(args);
    }
   ```

The latest gnu documentation can be found at [gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).
Warning Options are in [section 3.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) (look for `-Wmissing-format-attribute`).
Function Attributes are in [section 6.30](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) (look for *format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)*).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation has the answer you need. Particularly:

1. Yes
2. The one you have posted is correct (`format(printf, 1, 0)`). 1 because the format string is parameter 1, 0 because there are no variadic arguments to be checked.

Comment: In MyVariadicPrintf, I understand that the compiler will check the number and types of the arguments beginning at position 2 against the string at position 1. But in the case of MyPrintf, what does the compiler check?

Comment: In case of MyPrintf, it will only check for validity of the format string (eg. that it isn't something like "%_%")

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [GCC docs on gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes). As for the last question, my guess is that `MyPrintf` is not a template function and the only definition available takes `char const*` as the first argument so it feels safe making the suggestion.