# vsprintf and vsnprintf [-Wformat-nonliteral] warning on Clang 5.0

Tags: c, network-programming, clang, printf

i have this chunk of code

```
static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int level, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    int     errno_save;
    unsigned long n;
char    buf[MAXLINE];
    errno_save = errno;    
    #ifdef  HAVE_VSNPRINTF
vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);   /* this is safe */
    #else
vsprintf(buf ,fmt, ap);         /* this is not safe */
    #endif
n = strlen(buf);
if (errnoflag)
    snprintf(buf + n, sizeof(buf) - n, ": %s", strerror(errno_save));
strcat(buf, "\n");

if (daemon_proc) {
    syslog(level,"%s", buf);
} else {
    fflush(stdout);     
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(stderr);
}
return;
}
```

when i compile it (Clang 5.0.0 with -Weverything) i obtain those warnings:

```
Building C object lib/netutils/CMakeFiles/netutils.dir/error.c.o
/Users/User/Desktop/project.cmake/lib/netutils/error.c:98:16: warning: format string is        not a string literal [-Wformat-nonliteral]
    vsprintf(buf ,fmt, ap);                 /* this is not safe */
                  ^~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:66:57: note: expanded from
  macro 'vsprintf'__builtin___vsprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
                                                    ^
```

the same thing happens with this other function vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);

how can i fix this warning?

Thanks

Comment: You should change your `#else` clause to simply contain `#errro`. As it is, you have a very serious security hole on broken systems lacking `vsnprintf`. Alternatively, you could use `tmpfile` and `vfprintf` in the fallback case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the solution is to tell Clang that your `vsnprintf` is called within a function that implements the behaviour of the `printf` family of functions by, well, calling `vsnprintf`. You do this with an attribute, [as described here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#format-string-checking):

```
__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 0)))
static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int level, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    ...
}
```

This checks whether the format string is a literal on the calling function. As `err_doit` takes already a `va_list`, you should specify the format on the functions that call it, too. The second number, which is 0 here, should then be the argument index of the variadic argument, `...`. See [also this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996786/how-to-use-the-gcc-attribute-format).

Function attributes are a non-standard extension of gcc, which is also implemented for Clang. If you want to keep the code compiler independent, you should wrap the attributes in a macro that hides it for compilers that don't know attributes.

(Disclaimer: I couldn't check this with Clang, but it works for gcc. Edit: fixed wrong argument index in example)

Comment: Thanks :) This worked for me but according to the explanation in the documentation that i linked in your answer the correct way is    __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 0))) because the format is const char *fmt (third parameter).

Comment: Yes, I got that "not a string argument" error, too, but forgot to update the post. Sorry, I'll update it.

Comment: The above solution worked but i did not understand the concept behind the same . Can someone please explain?

Comment: @AnandSonawane: Gcc's and Clang's attributes can provide further information to the compiler.In this case, it will communicate to users of the function that a printf-like syntax is used and therefore will warn about format mismatches. And it tells the implementation that it's okay to use a format literal here, because `vprintf` will not be called directly, only via the given function, where `fmt` should be a literal.