# How to detect implicit conversion in vsnprintf by GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, printf

I want g++ to detect below incorrect implicit conversion in vsnprintf.
I try with:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -Wconversion -Wformat  test.cpp -o test.ext
```

But there is no warning. Code are as below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>


void PrintFError ( const char * format, ... )
{
  char buffer[256];
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vsnprintf (buffer,256,format, args);
  perror (buffer);
  va_end (args);
}


enum LEVEL
 {
     INFO = 1,
     WRN = 2
 };

int main ()
{

  PrintFError ("Error opening %s", WRN); // WRN is enum not char*, expecte some compile warning here

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related to [how-to-use-the-gcc-attribute-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996786/how-to-use-the-gcc-attribute-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add attribute to your function to allow gcc check:

```
void PrintFError ( const char * format, ... ) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))
```

Better to use variadic template now. something like

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void PrintFError (const char * format, Ts&&...args)
{
    char buffer[256];
    vsnprintf (buffer, 256, format, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    perror (buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of conversion happens at the call site when you pass arguments to `...`, not inside `printf`.

See [Variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) for more details.

Enumerators get converted to `int`. However, C++11 scoped enumerators do not get converted implicitly.

Comment: Yes, C++ 11 strong enumeration type is one solution for enum type. But replace legacy code is big effort. I hope to find some common way inside the utility function(log print).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), you could take advantage of their [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) ability, and *declare* your printing function as

```
void PrintFError ( const char * format, ...) 
   __attribute__(format(printf(1,2)));
```

Then latter *direct* uses of that function might trigger a warning.

BTW, you might also *customize* your recent `g++` (or `gcc`, if coding in C) compiler by extending it using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). Then you could define your own function attributes, and add your own checking optimization passes. This would take you at least a week of work, unless you are very familiar with GCC internals.

At last, in C++ (not in C), you could define your own output `operator <<` functions, and perhaps have a macro

```
 #define MY_ERROR_AT(Fil,Lin,Out) do { \ 
   std::cerr << Fil << ":" << Lin << ": " << Out << std::endl; } \
   while(0) 
 #define MY_ERROR(Out) MY_ERROR_AT(__FILE__,__LINE__,Out)
```

and code `MY_ERROR("x=" << x)` later in your program.

BTW, you might also play with C++ [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), but you should use a C++11 or C++14 compliant compiler (e.g. `g++ -std=c++14`).